# How should I make a (double-)negative sentence using "could have + past participle"?

Tags: modal-verbs, negation, past-participles, multiple-negation

If I want to say this sentence using *could have* plus past participle, then how should I say that?

> You were capable of **not going** there, but you went.

Is it correct to say:

> You could have not gone there.

---

PS:
I know that if I want to say that you were capable of going there, but you didn't go there, I can say:

> You could have gone there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this potentially tricky dialogue:

> “I went to the picnic yesterday.”
>
> “You didn’t! How could you have done that? You really shouldn’t’ve!”
>
> “What do you mean by *shouldn’t’ve*?”
>
> “I mean you should have not gone.”
>
> “Impossible! I could *not* have not gone.”

The issue is that “to go” and “to be able” can both experience negation, either separately or together.

1. I was able to go.
2. I was able to **not** go.
3. I was **not** able to go.
4. I was **not** able to **not** go.

I am using the simpler *to go* for *to have gone*, and *to be able* for *can/could* to simplify things. The corresponding versions are:

1. I could have gone.
2. I could have **not** gone.
3. I could **not** have gone.
4. I could **not** have **not** gone.

Comment: @J008 Yes, I sometimes do — when it is actually appropriate, which is admittedly not especially common. The point is that there is more than one piece in the verb phrase that one can negate, and it is even possible to negate both of them at the same time for added meaning. Both *could have* and *gone* can be negated: *“could **not** have gone”* and  *“could have **not** gone”* mean different things, and *“could **not** have **not** gone" means something else again. Does that make sense, or have I only confused you? I will try harder if so.

Answer (score 7):

> 1: *I could have not answered this question,* but...

Both OP's example and mine are completely grammatical, but it's worth pointing out that even native speakers (especially when not paying close attention) could be liable to misparse mine as...

> 2: *I could **not** have answered*
>    or
>    3: *I **couldn't** have answered*

...because ["**could not have**" is far more common than "**could have not**"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could%20not%20have%2Ccould%20have%20not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20have%20not%3B%2Cc0).
[image]

In my specific example there's a clear semantic distinction between my first version *(It would have been possible for me not to answer)* and the more common forms meaning *It would not have been possible for me to answer*.

That same ambiguity potentially exists in the present tense form...

> 4: *I **can not** answer*

But in practice that version would carry the strong implication *not answering is an option available to me*, because if the intended sense was *I am not able to answer* it would probably be written as...

> 5: *I **cannot** answer*
>    or
>    6: *I **can't** answer*

In *speech*, the less common sense could be conveyed by stressing *either* ***can*** or ***not*** (if only one of the two words is stressed, it steers the audience away from the one-word ***cannot*** version).

---

Another common way to steer the audience away from an unwanted misparsing is...

> 7: *I could **simply** not have answered*
>    8: *I could have **just** not answered*

...where introducing another word between ***could*** and ***not*** again steers the reader/audience towards the intended sense.

Comment: You have not answered the request to show her how to make a **double** negative out of this. I think you should not have not answered. :)

Comment: @J008 "Just" is often used as a "filler" word in that situation. "You could have just not gone there" (i.e. it was possible for you to go, and you did go, but you should not have gone) or "You just couldn't have gone there" (i.e. it was impossible for you to go, even if you wanted to go).

Comment: @tchrist: As you presumably anticipated, I **can't not** respond to your comment. But I would just say that OP's only reference to "double negative" is the bracketed **(double)** in the title itself (with no further mention in the actual question text). And I think for most learners (probably including OP) there are quite enough issues to take on board here without even bothering with that aspect (which at the end of the day is relatively trivial). The *really* important bit (which neither of us have covered that well) is *when does **not** modify what comes **before,** rather than **after?***